# how to achieve multi dimensional stacked barplot using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data frame and want to plot multiple dimensions on same axis.

```
df <- data.frame(Year = sample(2017:2018, 100, replace = T),
                 Months = sample(month.name, 100, replace = T),
                 catergory = sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace = T),
                 count = sample(1:1000, 100, replace = T),
                 Product = sample(c("Apple", "Orange", "Grapes", "Banana"), 
                                  100, replace = T)
)
```

I want to map `year` & `month` to the x-axis, `count` to the y-axis, and `catergory` to fill.

I need the output with year-month count but don't know how to represent product. Any best suggestion for the stacked bar plot?

Comment: Please post the code that you've been working on & draw the expected output in Paint/Word/PPT so folks can help

Comment: surely will try to plot the expected one @Tung

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want to use the `facet_XXX` approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was tried without using `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` but getting very difficult or my data is not supporting for that.
So using of `facet_wrap` i got the solution.

```
df$Months<-factor(df$Months,levels = month.name) ##Reordering the Months
df$Year<-factor(df$Year) ##changing to factorial

ggplot(df,aes(x=Months,y=count,fill=category))+ geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "stack")+
  facet_grid(Year~Product)+coord_flip()
```

[image: output]